# ipaddress.ip_network выдает ошибки, если в сети установлены биты хоста

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

Как исправить так, что бы я мог задавать любую подсеть?

Comment: Там есть другой объект для хоста с маской

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Interface

Для хоста с маской следует использовать ipaddress.IPv4Interface класс. И ipaddress.ip_interface(address) функция для получения